# Failed to validate the server name "iapps-in-dev-sql-server.privatelink.database.windows.net" Error retrieving database meta-data;

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, mssql-jdbc

I am getting the below error after the upgrade. It was working fine in jdk8 and spring boot version 1.5.3-release and MS Sql driver mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar

Now I upgraded jdk to 21 and spring-boot to 2.7.16 and using the below jdbc driver

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>12.4.2.jre11</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting a strange exception while connecting to the db. Please find the exception below. Please let me know how to resolve this issue

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Error retrieving database meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ("encrypt" property is set to "true" and "trustServerCertificate" property is set to "false" but the driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption: Error: Failed to validate the server name "iapps-in-dev-sql-server.privatelink.database.windows.net"in a certificate during Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) initialization. Name in certificate "cr11.indiacentral1-a.control.database.windows.net". ClientConnectionId:225fcdb4-f187-4250-9dcc-07def6542715)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory.createMetaDataProvider(CallMetaDataProviderFactory.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext.initializeMetaData(CallMetaDataContext.java:254)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compileInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:315)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compile(AbstractJdbcCall.java:298)
    at com.gtl.industryapp.commonservice.middleware.service.db.helper.CommonServiceDatabaseCommunicator.setDefaultParameter(CommonServiceDatabaseCommunicator.java:178)
    at com.gtl.industryapp.commonservice.middleware.service.db.helper.CommonServiceDatabaseCommunicator.getResult(CommonServiceDatabaseCommunicator.java:157)
    at com.gtl.industryapp.commonservice.middleware.service.db.helper.CommonServiceDatabaseCommunicator.getSPResult(CommonServiceDatabaseCommunicator.java:70)
    at com.gtl.industryapp.commonservice.middleware.service.db.helper.CommonServiceDatabaseCommunicator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c9e927a0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.invokeMethod(CglibAopProxy.java:386)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.access$000(CglibAopProxy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at com.gtl.industryapp.commonservice.middleware.service.db.helper.CommonServiceDatabaseCommunicator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$37381077.getSPResult(<generated>)
    at com.gtl.industryapp.commonservice.middleware.service.impl.GeneralDataServiceImpl.getData(GeneralDataServiceImpl.java:44)
    at com.gtl.industryapp.commonservice.middleware.service.impl.helper.AppStoreServiceHelper.executeForApi(AppStoreServiceHelper.java:56)
    at com.gtl.industryapp.commonservice.middleware.service.impl.AppStoreServiceImpl.getAppDataForApi(AppStoreServiceImpl.java:44)
    at com.gtl.industryapp.commonservice.middleware.controller.AppStoreApiServiceController.getAPPData(AppStoreApiServiceController.java:39)
    at com.gtl.industryapp.commonservice.middleware.controller.AppStoreApiServiceController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$701775b8.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:792)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:762)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterAdvice.java:49)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:762)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:762)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:762)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:707)
    at com.gtl.industryapp.commonservice.middleware.controller.AppStoreApiServiceController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$38c57cc5.getAPPData(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at com.gtl.iapps.db.multitenancy.routing.intercepter.SecurityContextFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityContextFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ("encrypt" property is set to "true" and "trustServerCertificate" property is set to "false" but the driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption: Error: Failed to validate the server name "iapps-in-dev-sql-server.privatelink.database.windows.net"in a certificate during Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) initialization. Name in certificate "cr11.indiacentral1-a.control.database.windows.net". ClientConnectionId:225fcdb4-f187-4250-9dcc-07def6542715)

some times it come as
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ("encrypt" property is set to "true" and "trustServerCertificate" property is set to "false" but the driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption: Error: Failed to validate the server name "iapps-in-dev-sql-server.privatelink.database.windows.net"in a certificate during Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) initialization. Name in certificate "**cr11.indiacentral1-a.control.database.windows.net**". ClientConnectionId:225fcdb4-f187-4250-9dcc-07def6542715)

Some other times as
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ("encrypt" property is set to "true" and "trustServerCertificate" property is set to "false" but the driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption: Error: Failed to validate the server name "iapps-in-dev-sql-server.privatelink.database.windows.net"in a certificate during Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) initialization. Name in certificate "**cr13.indiacentral1-a.control.database.windows.net**". ClientConnectionId:225fcdb4-f187-4250-9dcc-07def6542715)

Database is in azure .I am looking for a solution for this issue.

Comment: Well it feels odd that it would work with an older JDK?  The error is telling you that you are trying to do an SSL connection towards 'iapps-in-dev-sql-server.privatelink.database.windows.net' using a Certificate that has a server name as 'cr11.indiacentral1-a.control.database.windows.net' which dont match OR your Certificate is no longer valid.

Please see https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-385-failed-to-validate-the-server-name-in-a/ba-p/3859003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually telling you what is wrong.

```
"encrypt" property is set to "true" and "trustServerCertificate" property is set to "false"
```

The documentation states the following:

```
encrypt = true
trustServerCertificate = false or blank
hostNameInCertificate = value
trustStore = blank
trustStorePassword = blank
The driver requests to use TLS encryption with the server.

If the server requires the client to support TLS encryption or if the server supports encryption, the driver will initiate the TLS certificate exchange.

The driver will validate the TLS certificate's subject value by using the value specified for the hostNameInCertificate property.

If the server isn't configured to support encryption, the driver will raise an error and terminate the connection.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-ssl-support?view=sql-server-ver16

Which means that because `encrypt=true` and `trustServerCertificate=false`, then it will enforce validating the Certificate TLS Chain, which you probably dont have or have but is invalid. (Such as the TLS Subject value does not match the hostName of the server

---

Now if you look at the github code for the  mssql-jdbc

You will see that in version 6.1.0, both `encrypt=false` and `trustServerCertificate=false` which means

```
encrypt = false or blank
trustServerCertificate = any
hostNameInCertificate = any
trustStore = any
trustStorePassword = any
The driver won't force the server to support TLS encryption. If the server has a self-signed certificate, the driver initiates the TLS certificate exchange. The TLS certificate won't be validated and only the credentials (in the login packet) are encrypted.

If the server requires the client to support TLS encryption, the driver will initiate the TLS certificate exchange. The TLS certificate won't be validated, but the entire communication will be encrypted.
```

https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/cd2f4c87403aa6a41cbe8b3dda3106392dc6ee0b/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver.java#L917

---

And if you check the version 12.4.2, it is now enforcing TLS validation by having both `encrypt=true` and `trustServerCertificate=false`.

https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/v12.4.2/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver.java#L610

---

So you need to have the Database server certificate on your Java truststore to be able to connect.

or set `encrypt=true` and `trustServerCertificate=true` which is not secure, because it essentially means don't validate the TLS Certificate.

```
encrypt = true
trustServerCertificate = true
hostNameInCertificate = any
trustStore = any
trustStorePassword = any
The driver requests to use TLS encryption with the server.

If the server requires the client to support TLS encryption or if the server supports encryption, the driver will initiate the TLS certificate exchange. If the trustServerCertificate property is set to "true", the driver won't validate the TLS certificate.

If the server isn't configured to support encryption, the driver will raise an error and terminate the connection.
```

Comment: Thats correct trustServerCertificate=true solved the issue